# JSON string to PHP JSON array

Tags: php, arrays, json, google-visualization

I have the following string:

```
{
legend: {
    position: 'top',
    textStyle: {
        color: '#676a6c'
    }
},
colors: ["#1c84c6", "#f8ac59", "#1ab394", "ed5565", "5bc0de", "f0ad4e"],
title: "",
titleTextStyle: {
    color: '#676a6c'
},
hAxis: {
    title: 'Gemiddelde marge per verkooporder',
    textStyle: {
        color: '#676a6c',
    },
    titleTextStyle: {
        color: '#676a6c',
        italic: 'false',
        bold: 'false',
    },
    format: 'currency'
},
vAxis: {
    title: '# verkooporders per product',
    textStyle: {
        color: '#676a6c',
    },
    titleTextStyle: {
        color: '#676a6c',
        italic: 'false',
        bold: 'false',
    }
},
bubble: {
    textStyle: {
        color: 'transparent',
        auraColor: 'none',
    },
},
width: "100%",
isStacked: true,
fontName: 'open sans', //Choose from Times-Roman, Arial
fontSize: 13,
height: 350,
};
```

I want to convert this to an php array, which i can JSON_encode() later on. What's the best way to iterate through this JSON array?

Do i need to loop through the string with foreach()?

Comment: Will this work? http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: try to `json_decode()` this json string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use the `json_decode()` function it should do the trick:

```
$str = "...your JSON string here...";
$parsed = json_decode($str, true);
```

Notes:

1) Passing `true` to `json_decode()` will make it return an array rather than objects. If you leave it off you'll get objects back; it's down to which you prefer.

2) You should check the result of `json_last_error()` to see if any errors occurred. If it returns `JSON_ERROR_NONE` it means the string was parsed correctly.

Comment: json_decode() returns null. I checked json_last_error() and it gives a syntax error. I think this is because my key and values aren't surrounded by double quotes. Is this correct?

Comment: The code is correct, but I'm afraid your JSON is bad: try running it through http://jsonlint.com/ and you'll see.

Comment: Is there a way to surround the key-value pairs in my JSON with double quotes in php?

Comment: Also, you should remove commas after last element of the each object? for example: `textStyle: {color: '#676a6c',},` should be `textStyle: {color: '#676a6c'},`